# Cannot derive Typeable for associated data family

Tags: haskell, type-families, derived-instances

I'm trying to derive `Typeable` for an associated data family like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

import Data.Typeable

class Test a where
  data DTest a :: *

instance Test () where
  data DTest () = Foo
    deriving Typeable
```

But I'm getting the following error message and it leaves me a little puzzled:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Test             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:12:14:
    Cannot eta-reduce to an instance of form
      instance (...) => Typeable DTest
    In the data instance declaration for ‘DTest’
```

Could someone please elaborate as to what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be related to `ghc` 7.8.4. I tried the same code snippet with
`ghc` 7.10.1 and it compiled.